# How to obtain databse url etc without the heroku CLI

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, jdbc

I am using Heroku PostgreSQL in my Java application and obtain the database url, username, database name, and password like so

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("sslmode","require");
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a myMegaCoolApplication");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(postgres)://([^:]+):([^@]+)@(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(br.readLine());
m.find();
props.setProperty("user",m.group(2));
props.setProperty("password",m.group(3));
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:"+m.group(1)+"ql://"+m.group(4),props);
```

Here one needs to have the `heroku` tool installed on a local machine. Can I do without it? The goal is to be able to ship the Java jar-file alone, without the requiring the user to install `heroku`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an HTTP request to the [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars) to retrieve config vars for an app.

A convenient way to do this is with the [heroku.jar](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar) client library. For example

```
HerokuAPI api = new HerokuAPI(apiKey);
Map<String, String> config = api.listConfig("myExistingApp");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> var : config.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(var.getKey() + "=" + var.getValue());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. As a follow-up, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641386/heroku-api-adding-the-jar-into-netbeans. I'll accept yours as the answer after we resolve that issue.

Comment: For some reason, the `config` variable had only one key, "DATABASE_URL", which I had to parse as shown in my original post.