# Heroku API: adding the jar into NetBeans

Tags: java, heroku, netbeans, jar

Following up on [How to obtain databse url etc without the heroku CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624335/how-to-obtain-databse-url-etc-without-the-heroku-cli) I have added https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar to my NetBeans project's library: "Add JAR/Folder" (I copied the jar first to /home/username/netbeans-8.2/ide/modules/ext) But `HerokuAPI` is not being recognized, and `Alt-Space` does not show any suggestions for imports, so I guess netbeans simply has not recognized the jar's contents. Maybe this thing is hidden in the default package, and so I can't import it?

EDIT: Here is the image 
[image]

So, it *is* in the default package after all? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new -- now Maven-based -- project and resolve the dependency using `pom.xml`, as explained on https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar